# Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

Hello I have problem with this query

```
INSERT INTO radacct 
    (acctsessionid,acctuniqueid,username, 
    realm,nasipaddress,nasportid, nasporttype,acctstarttime,
    acctupdatetime, acctstoptime,acctsessiontime, acctauthentic,
     connectinfo_start,connectinfo_stop, acctinputoctets, 
     acctoutputoctets,calledstationid, callingstationid, 
     acctterminatecause,servicetype,framedprotocol, 
     framedipaddress,dup,t_session, nas_name,groupname,
     percent_q,down_uq,up_uq,all_tu,up_dq,dwon_dq,time_dq,t_update)
     VALUES ('80a000cc', '678593b487e8a42f68685f896b9d6d5d',
     '1', '', '10.40.47.1', 'WAN6', 'Wireless-802.11', 
     DATE_SUB('2019-05-18 03:06:18' , INTERVAL 10934 SECOND), 
     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), NULL, 10934, '', '', '',
     '0' << 32 | '29802288', '0' << 32 | '739955022', 
     'hotspot1', '3C:D9:2B:50:B2:BC', '', '', '', '10.40.47.44',
     '80a000cc', unix_timestamp(), 'Router 21',
     COALESCE((SELECT groupname FROM `radusergroup` WHERE username = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1),'0'),
     COALESCE((SELECT userinfo.percent_now,SUM(r1.acctoutputoctets * (r1.percent_q/100)),SUM(r1.acctinputoctets * (r1.percent_q/100)),SUM(`r1`.`acctsessiontime`) FROM radacct as `r1` INNER JOIN userinfo ON (userinfo.username=r1.username) WHERE r1.username = '1' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(r1.acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) >= userinfo.updatedate),(SELECT 100,SUM(r2.acctoutputoctets),SUM(r2.acctinputoctets),SUM(`r9`.`acctsessiontime`) FROM radacct as `r2` INNER JOIN radcheck ON (radcheck.username=r2.username AND radcheck.is_card ='1' AND `radcheck`.`attribute`='Cleartext-Password' ) WHERE r2.username = '1')), 
     COALESCE((SELECT SUM(`r5`.`acctinputoctets` * (r5.percent_q/100)),SUM(`r6`.`acctoutputoctets` * (r6.percent_q/100)),SUM(`r6`.`acctsessiontime`)  FROM `radacct` as `r5` WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`r5`.`acctstarttime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') AND r5.username = '1'),(SELECT 0,0,0)), '')
```

Comment: The error message that you are getting is missing! You should count  then number of fields after 'radacct(', and before the ')', and that count should match the number of fields after 'VALUES(', en before the final ')'.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the last two COASLESCE() function in your query:

For an example, you are expecting 3 values from the below `COALESCE()` function, but it doesn't

```
COALESCE((
        SELECT SUM(`r5`.`acctinputoctets` * (r5.percent_q / 100)),
               SUM(`r6`.`acctoutputoctets` * (r6.percent_q / 100)),
               SUM(`r6`.`acctsessiontime`)
        FROM `radacct` AS `r5`
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`r5`.`acctstarttime`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
            AND r5.username = '1'
        ), (
        SELECT 0,
            0,
            0
        )),
```

You need to change it to individual select value, then it will work.